# Cannot compile my TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I use Ovearleaf and it gives me a time-out because of the following TikZ picture:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,scale=1.4]
    \tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
    hollow node /.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
    }
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=12mm, sibling distance = 25 mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance = 15 mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=17mm, sibling distance = 10 mm]
    
    \node(0)[solid node,label=right:{Naturaleza}]{}
    child[grow=up]{node[solid node, label=above:{$F_B$}]{}
    child[grow=left]{node(1)[solid node, label below:{}]{}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(1;1)$}]{} edge from parent node [above]{$c$}}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
    edge from parent node [above]{$cert$}
    }
    child[grow=right]{node(2)[solid node, label below:{}]{}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(0;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [above]{$c$}}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
    edge from parent node [above]{$Ncert$}
    }
    edge from parent node[right]{$0,5$}
    }
    child[grow=down]{node[solid node, label=below:{$F_M$}]{}
    child[grow=left]{node(2)[solid node, label=above:{}]{}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(0;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [above]{$c$}}
    child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
    edge from parent node [above]{$cert$}
    }
    child[grow=left]{node(4)[solid node, label=above:{}]{}
    child{node[hollow node, label=right:{$(0;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [above]{$c$}}
    child{node[hollow node, label=right:{$(2;0)$}]{} edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
    edge from parent node [above]{$Ncert$}
    }
    edge from parent node[right]{$0,5$}
    }
    \draw[dashed, rounded corners=10]($(1)+(-.45,.45)$)rectangle($(2)+(.45,-.45)$);
    \draw[dashed, rounded corners=10]($(3)+(-.45,.45)$)rectangle($(2)+(.45,-.45)$);
    \node at ($(1)!5!(2)$){Consumidor}
    \node at ($(3)!5!(4)$){Consumidor}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You code fragment cannot be compiled. For compilation, please be so kind and extend it to complete small document which begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. In its preamble please load only to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: Probably some forgotten semicolon somewhere. In any case do a minimal working example.

Answer (score 3):

Changes I made:

- Add `\documentclass{article}` and the `document` environment. Load `tikz` package and its `calc` library.
- Add missing semicolons at the end of all three `\node` commands.
- Change `hollow node /.style` to `hollow node/.style`.
- Change two `label below:{}` to `label=below:{}`.
- Adjust code indent, non-functional.

Now it almost compiles, except for the unknown node name `3`.

PS: Is the large node tree `\node {} {child {node{}} child {node{}} ...};` generated by some program? If so, what's the name of the program?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,scale=1.4]
\tikzset{
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5}
}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=12mm, sibling distance = 25 mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm, sibling distance = 15 mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=17mm, sibling distance = 10 mm]

\node(0)[solid node,label=right:{Naturaleza}]{}
  child[grow=up]{
    node[solid node, label=above:{$F_B$}]{}
    child[grow=left]{
      node(1)[solid node, label=below:{}]{}
      child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(1;1)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [above]{$c$}}
      child{node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
        edge from parent node [above]{$cert$}
    }
    child[grow=right]{
      node(2)[solid node, label=below:{}]{}
      child{
        node[hollow node, label=left:{$(0;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [above]{$c$}
      }
      child{
        node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}
      }
      edge from parent node [above]{$Ncert$}
    }
    edge from parent node[right]{$0,5$}
  }
  child[grow=down]{
    node[solid node, label=below:{$F_M$}]{}
    child[grow=left]{node(2)[solid node, label=above:{}]{}
    child{
      node[hollow node, label=left:{$(0;0)$}]{}
      edge from parent node [above]{$c$}
    }
    child{
      node[hollow node, label=left:{$(2;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}}
        edge from parent node [above]{$cert$}
    }
    child[grow=left]{
      node(4)[solid node, label=above:{}]{}
      child{
        node[hollow node, label=right:{$(0;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [above]{$c$}
      }
      child{
        node[hollow node, label=right:{$(2;0)$}]{}
        edge from parent node [below]{$nc$}
      }
      edge from parent node [above]{$Ncert$}
    }
    edge from parent node[right]{$0,5$}
  };
  \draw[dashed, rounded corners=10]($(1)+(-.45,.45)$)rectangle($(2)+(.45,-.45)$);
  \draw[dashed, rounded corners=10]($(3)+(-.45,.45)$)rectangle($(2)+(.45,-.45)$);
  \node at ($(1)!5!(2)$){Consumidor};
  \node at ($(3)!5!(4)$){Consumidor};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How you compile your MWE? I got error: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named `3' is known.`. It is not defined in OP nor in your code ...

Comment: @Zarko Yes I leave node `3` undefined (because I don't know which node should be named `3`) and have mentioned this in my answer. The MWE is compiled with CLI option `-interaction=nonstopmode`.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this part of your explanation. Anyway, obtained result of code help me to construct image code from scratch ... +1 for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

- most of the errors in your MWE  are listed in @muzimuzhi Z answer
- I must confess that I went lost in your "forest" of child nodes, so it may happen, that some labels in MWE below are wrong or on wrong position
- my estimation is that code for your image draw without use of `tree` syntax is simpler and (far) more clear:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 24mm,
   FIT/.style = {draw, dashed, rounded corners, inner sep=5mm,
                 fit=#1, node contents={}}, 
   dot/.style = {circle, inner sep=1.5, label=#1,
                 node contents={}},
  hdot/.style = {dot=#1, draw},
  sdot/.style = {dot=#1, draw, fill},
      every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, 
                            inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                        ]
\node  (n1a)    [hdot=left:{(1;1)}];
\node  (n2)     [sdot=, below right=of n1a];
\node  (n3)     [sdot=above:$F_B$, right=of n2];
\node  (n4)     [sdot={}, right=of n3];
\node  (n5a)    [sdot=right:{(2;0)},    above right=of n4];
\node  (n1b)    [hdot=left:{(2;0)},
                 below left=of n2];
\node  (n5b)    [sdot=right:{(0;0)},    below right=of n4];
%
\node  (n6)     [sdot=right:Naturaleza, below=of n1b -| n3];
%
\node  (n7a)    [hdot=left:{(0;0)},     below=of n1b |- n6];
\node  (n8)     [sdot=, below right=of n7a];
\node  (n9)     [sdot=below:$F_M$,      right=of n8];
\node  (n7b)    [hdot=left:{(2;0)},     below left =of n8];
%%%% arrows
\draw   (n1a)   edge ["$c$"]    (n2)
        (n1b)   edge ["$nc$" '] (n2)
        (n2)    edge ["$cert$"]     (n3)    
        (n3)    edge ["$Ncert$"]    (n4)
        (n4)    edge ["$nc$"]   (n5a)
        (n4)    edge ["$c$" ']  (n5b)
%       
        (n3)    edge ["{$0,5$}" sloped=false]  (n6)    
        (n6)    edge ["{$0,5$}" sloped=false]  (n9)  
%
        (n7a)   edge ["$c$"]    (n8)
        (n7b)   edge ["$nc$" '] (n8)
        (n8)    edge ["$Ncert$"]     (n9)
         ;
%%%% dashed boxes
\node [FIT=(n2) (n8)];
    \node (aux1) [dot=, left=11mm of n6];
    \node (aux2) [dot=, left=11mm of n9];
\node [FIT=(aux1) (aux2)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]